# Next.js URL rewrites and middleware doesn't include headers

Tags: reactjs, .net, next.js, auth0

I'm trying to redirect API requests from url http://localhost:3000//backend to a different .net core project hosted on http://localhost:5186/api with a JWT token in the header.  The problem is when I get the request on the .net core side the headers are not included.  I'm assuming this is because it's technically a different domain?  How do I get next.js to include the headers?

Here's my next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
async rewrites() {
  return [
    {
       source: "/backend/:path*",
       destination: `${API_URL}/:path*`,
    },
  ];
},
```

};

Middleware.ts

```
 import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
// middleware.js
import { withMiddlewareAuthRequired, getSession } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0/edge';

export async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
 
  const res = NextResponse.next();
  const user = await getSession(req, res);

  if (user) {
    req.headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${user.accessToken}`)
  }

  console.log(res.headers);
  return res;
};
```